# Minimum cost flow problem - optimality on subgraphs

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, discrete-optimization

Consider the minimum cost flow problem as in [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem#:~:text=The%20minimum%2Dcost%20flow%20problem,flow%20through%20a%20flow%20network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem#:%7E:text=The%20minimum%2Dcost%20flow%20problem,flow%20through%20a%20flow%20network).

Suppose $f_0$ is an optimal solution for $G$ with given costs and capacities. Let $H$ be a subgraph of $G$, let $e\in H$ be an edge and now consider the following variation of the min-cost flow problem on $G$:

- We impose the additional constraint that the flow on $e$ equals some given integer $X$.
- We impose the additional constraint that the flow on each edge of $G$ which is not $H$ equals the flow given by $f_0$.

Let $f_1$ be the new optimal solution (assume that such exists). If $S_0$ and $S_1$ are the total costs from the edges of $H$ (under $f_0$ and $f_1$, respectively), is it always true that $S_0 \leq S_1$?

(Of course, it must be the case that the total cost from the edges of $G$ has become greater or stayed the same. The question is whether this is also forced on subgraphs of $G$.)

I have tested this with python code on several graphs and so far have not found a counterexample; however I also do not know how to proceed for a proof. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Why do you say that the total cost does not increase on $G$? This does not seem true to me, unless I am misunderstanding something.

Comment: Oops, I am very stupid, I should reverse all inequalities, thanks!

Comment: But this doesn't seem to be true either. E.g. if there is a cut-edge and we prescribe that the flow going through it is zero, then $f_1$ will necessarily be the zero flow with $S_1 = 0$, irrespective of what $S_0$ was. Maybe you are thinking that the min cost property of $f_0$ implies $S_0 \leq S_1$, but this need not be true if $f_1$ is not a maximum flow (in the standard sense, not with respect to the constraint on $e$).

Comment: Yep, edited again, thanks! (In the newest version if you just put $0$ on an edge and do not change anything else the problem should become unfeasible I think? Because the total flow must depend only on "d" and so changing a single variable would violate this.)

Comment: But if you require that the flow does not change on edges outside of $H$, and say that the total cost does not decrease, this immediately implies that the total cost on $H$ must not decrease (since outside $H$ the cost didn't change), doesn't it? Also, I do not see how your edit ensures that the total cost does not decrease, since we can just take the previous example with $H = G$. What do you mean by the problem becoming unfeasible?

Comment: I meant it with $H$ consisting only of this edge and not for any $H$.

Comment: Hmmmmm wow it is so simple... indeed "the flow does not change on edges outside of $H$, and say that the total cost does not decrease, this immediately implies that the total cost on $H$ must not decrease" is the key, thanks a lot!